# How to make it possible for files to be downloaded without security warnings

Tags: windows

So I have made a program for Windows that I want to distribute. I have packed it into an inno script exe file. But when someone is trying to open this file after having downloaded it, they get all kinds of security warnings. What do you do to avoid this, so that the file is considered safe to open and run? I guess the program has to be registered somewhere, somehow. But where and how do I do this, and how much does it cost?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much it costs depends on the certificate type and where you buy it, and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Purchase a EV certificate and sign your installer
2. Be popular and have many people download your application.

SmartScreen warnings will go away after many people install your software. The certificate should make the process faster and it will remember it for newer versions of your software.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-smartscreen/microsoft-defender-smartscreen-overview) claims you can submit your file [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission/) but I don't know how effective that is...